# Revivify v. Finger of Death, part 748

Tags: spells, undead

I've found dozens of questions about this, but not the one I want to ask.

Bob the Rogue is killed by a Finger of Death from Darth Villainous. Joe the Cleric has the next action in the initiative order and is standing close by.

According to FoD description: "A humanoid killed by this spell rises at the start of your next turn as a Zombie."

If it isn't the start of Darth's next turn does Revivify work?

P.S. As a Bard with Secrets of Magic you could learn Contingency & Revivify, which is another flavor of this conundrum.

Comment: What game and edition are you asking about? Please include a tag to indicate this. [There are thousands of RPGs](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-just-dont-understand-the-scope-of-the-rpg-lands) and we can't provide an answer until we know which one the question is about.

Comment: Bardic "Secrets of Magic" is a specific 5e, as is the specific zombie mechanic of the Finger of death.  3.5 and pathfinder finger does not raise the dead.

I can answer this question.

Comment: @PlayPatrice and it is very likely D&D 5e but all the same, [we don't guess the system](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6867/what-to-do-when-an-edit-guesses-the-system-being-used-rather-than-waiting-for-th) and need to wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: Here is that question answered for D&D5e: [Can revivify prevent zombification from finger of death?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/132396)